# Where can I find a list of Meteor template events?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I couldn't find this information in the Meteor documentation.
So I wrote

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log("!");
  })
})
```

'scroll window' displays no result.

Answer (score 1):

There is no list of Meteor template events because they are the same as DOM events (`click`, `change`, `submit`, etc...).

However, if you want to run code when the DOM is ready, you have to use `Meteor.startup` client-side :

`client/startup.js`

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log("scroll event !");
  });
});
```

Comment: This works, but I don't have an access to router's data.